# Check rank ordering in R

Tags: r

I want to check rank ordering of decile values. It should be in descending order. It means the first decile must have maximum percentage score. The column looks like below -

```
pct.of.total
13.84
12.80
13.15
11.76
11.07
9.00
9.69
8.30
7.27
3.11
```

In this case, 3rd decile (`13.15` ) has more score than 2nd decile (`12.80`). If this is the case, i want R function to return - `"Rank Ordering - Not satisfied at 3rd decile"`. If values are in descending order, i want R function to return - `"Rank Ordering - Satisfied"`.

I am using this code -

```
  message( "Rank Ordering Status : ", all(diff(final.gaint$pct.of.total) <= 0))
```

The problem with the code - It does not return the decile level in which break exists in order and also i want "Satisfied" in place of "TRUE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n <- sapply(which(diff(final.gain$pct.of.total) > 0), getOrd)
if(all(diff(final.gain$pct.of.total) <= 0)) {
  return("Rank Ordering - Satisfied")
} else {
  sprintf("Rank Ordering - Not satisfied at %s decile", n)
}
```

An added bonus from this site [here](http://www.phillipburger.net/wordpress/ordinal-number-suffix-function-in-r/) for a function that formats the ordinal number.

```
getOrd <- function(num) {
  result <- ""
  if (!(num %% 100 %in% c(11, 12, 13))) {
    result <- switch(as.character(num %% 10), 
                     "1" = {paste0(num, "st")}, 
                     "2" = {paste0(num, "nd")},
                     "3" = {paste0(num, "rd")},
                     paste0(num, "th"))
  } else {
    result <- paste0(num, "th")
  }
  result
}
```